# Javascript invoking a function multiple times shorthand

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have been looking around for a while, and cant seem to find the answer for this.  I do not know if it is possible, but am just curious.  
Suppose I have a simple function:
`function foo(name){alert(name);}`

Also suppose that I have to invoke this function several times with several different names:

`foo("bar"); foo("blahh"); foo("myName"); foo("yourName");`

Is there a shorthand for this?
For Example:`foo("bar":"blahh":"myName":"yourName");`
This example is trivial, but in practice that principal could be very useful.  If there is some kind of jQuery solution I am open to that as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a generalization of other answers:

```
Function.prototype.sequence = function(vals) {
   for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; ++i) this(vals[i]);
}
```

this will add the `sequence` method to all functions. So you can use it with any function:

```
function foo() {....}

foo.sequence(["bar","blah","myName","yourName"]);
```

Answer (score 7):

You could put your parameters in an array and iterate through it:

```
params = ["bar", "blahh", "myName", "yourName"];
for (var i=0; i<params.length; i++) 
    foo(params[i]);
```

If the func takes multiple args, you can put arrays in the arrays:

```
params = [[1,"one"], [2,"two"], [5,"five"]];
for (var i=0; i<params.length; i++) 
    foobar(params[i][0], params[i][1]);
```

or

```
params = [[1,"one"], [2,"two"], [5,"five"]];
for (var i=0; i<params.length; i++) 
    foobar.apply(null, params[i]);
```

Comment: For the second case, consider using `apply`. I like where it's going.

Comment: Pass in `window` to apply maintain consistency :p

Comment: @pst: i think `window` is used by default if i give it `null` isn't it?

Comment: Good question. I just realized I don't know :)

Comment: The last example with `.apply(null, params[i])` is seriously nice. Good work @Claudiu

Answer (score 3):

Think of the task as *applying each element in a sequence, in turn, to the given function*. In jQuery this can be done as:

```
function foo(name){ alert(name) }
$.each(["bar","blah","myName","yourName"], function (index, value) {
   foo(value)
})
```

The extra function is required because the [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) callback is passed the index and value as parameters. It would be nice if the value was first :(

Compare with (a modified `foo` function):

```
function foo(index, name){ alert(name) }
$.each(["bar","blah","myName","yourName"], foo)
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

You could pass an array to the function:

```
function foo(vals) {
   for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; ++i) {
       alert(vals[i]); 
   }
}

foo(["bar","blah","myName","yourName"]);
```

Comment: Yes, it can be inverted. Does require modifying `foo` though :(

Answer (score 2):

Actually you could do something like this:

```
function foo(){
for (var i=0; i< arguments.length; i++){
         alert(arguments[i]);
     }
}
```

and then you can call it with as many arguments you like:

```
foo('miao', 'baw');
```

//alerts miao and then baw

Comment: Killing me for not having a `var i`! +1 for showing the use of arguments, even though it requires modification to `foo`.